# Understanding LINQ Queries and ViewModels

Tags: c#, sql, linq, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I have three simple tables - usergroups, staff, and salutations. All have ID, Name/Desc, and Active columns. The Usergroups are also assigned an optional staff ID, and the staff are assigned a non-optional salutation ID. I wish to query these tables to return a complete list of all active usergroups, with their related staff members (is any), and *their* related salutations.

A working SQL query is as follows:

```
        SELECT grp.ID, grp.Desc, grp.Active, sub.Name, sub.Desc
        FROM Tbl_UserGroup AS grp
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT st.ID, st.Name, sal.Desc
            FROM PrmTbl_Staff AS st
            LEFT JOIN PrmTbl_Salutation AS sal ON st.SalutationID = sal.ID
            WHERE 1
        ) AS sub ON grp.StaffID = sub.ID
        WHERE grp.Active = TRUE
        ORDER BY grp.ID DESC
```

I have a ViewModel as follows:

```
public class StaffUserGroup
{
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public string GroupDesc { get; set; }
    public bool GroupActive { get; set; }

    public int? StaffID { get; set; }
    public string StaffName { get; set; }

    public string SalutationName { get; set; }

    public List<PrmTbl_Staff> StaffsList { get; set; }

}
```

And an attempt at a LINQ query:

```
IEnumerable<Tbl_UserGroup> grpsQuery;

grpsQuery = from grp in db.Tbl_UserGroups
            join sub in(
                from st in db.PrmTbl_Staffs
                join sal in db.PrmTbl_Salutations on st.SalutationID equals sal.ID
                select new { StID = st.ID, st.Name, Salt = sal.Desc }
            ) on grp.StaffID equals sub.StID
            where grp.Active = true
            orderby grp.ID descending
            select new { grp.ID, grp.Desc, grp.Active, sub.Name, sub.Salt, sub.StID };
```

Which is loaded in my Controller:

```
        var viewModel = grpsQuery.Select(group =>
            new StaffUserGroup
            {
                GroupID = group.GroupID,
                GroupDesc = group.GroupDesc,
                GroupActive = group.GroupActive,

                StaffID = group.StaffID,
                StaffName = group.StaffName,

                SalutationName = group.SalutationName,

                StaffsList = rtrnStaff
            }
        );
```

Note that intellisense was flagging identically named columns between the sub query and the main query, so I introduced some aliases. I also wish to pass to the view a dropdown list of all available staff, hence the List in the viewmodel.

I am getting an error on the select call in the LINQ statement: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#4>' to '<...StaffUserGroup> An explicit conversion exists. Are you missing a cast?`

I don't know

- Why I need a ViewModel when I can just query the data I need directly to the Controller
- What the ViewModel class then actually *does* with the data retrieved from the query - does it filter it? Construct an object from it? From my background in PHP and MySQL, what would be a comparison?
- How to query specific columns from a table. I using `select new {}`, because I'm assuming that's equivalent?
- Why the above LINQ statement doesn't work.

I can post Models, Views, or Controllers if needed. Any help and advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You use viewmodels to separate presentation (validation, display attributes, etc) from business logic (objets with their methods).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Question 1

> Why I need a ViewModel when I can just query the data I need directly to the Controller

A ViewModel is a [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object) that you write which defines exactly what a view needs in order to display itself correctly.

For example, Let's suppose you have a page (view) that welcomes a user.

> Welcome, **Bob**. Your last visit was **2013-10-11**.

A ViewModel is a simple class that defines exactly the things that the view needs.

1. The user's name
2. The user's last visit

Therefore:

```
public class UserDetailsViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastVisit { get; set; }
}
```

It's (usually) the controller's responsibility to create the ViewModel, ensure it's populated,  give it to the view and finally return the view. The controller doesn't do much else; its responsibilities are limited and the code in an action should be fairly small.

The **reason** that you do this is because it's *good practice*. But that's not good enough, let me explain.

It is possible to simply run a query, return an IEnumerable of some domain object (for example a list of users) and give that to a view. This is done in many MVC demos. The problem is it's very limited/restrictive. What happens if you want to change what the view displays later? What happens if the domain model changes slightly? It's easier to manage and change things when they are neatly organised and concerns are separated.

## Question 2

> What the ViewModel class then actually does with the data retrieved from the query - does it filter it? Construct an object from it? From my background in PHP and MySQL, what would be a comparison?

The ViewModel is a concept that is native (or at least common) to certain [architectural patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern) such as [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel). The ViewModel doesn't really 'do' anything. It doesn't do any logic; it has no methods. It just contains a list of properties (and attributes) which define what a view that is using this ViewModel will need.

There isn't exactly a PHP equivalent because a ViewModel isn't specific to .NET. It's just a concept that is associated with MVC, MVVM and so on. The PHP equivalent would be a PHP MVC ViewModel. Remember that ASP.NET MVC is just an implementation of the MVC pattern. PHP has its own MVC implementations.

## Question 3

> How to query specific columns from a table. I using select new {}, because I'm assuming that's equivalent?

This depends on how you're doing it. [EntityFramework](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) is an object-relational mapper that is often used in ASP.NET MVC applications. In this way, you don't query your underlying storage or columns directly. Instead EF will map the tables and columns to .NET objects and you manipulate those.

I'd recommand you try to stay with dealing with objects, rather than creating anonymous types as you go and trying to grab specific columns. Remember that [LINQ isn't SQL](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_in_Kansas_anymore). The approach shouldn't be "Query this table, grab these columns, where this clause" but instead should be "From this group of objects, grab the object here, where this clause".

For example:

```
var query = from user in Users
            where user.FirstName == "Bob"
            select user;
```

## Question 4

> Why the above LINQ statement doesn't work.

As the description says you're trying to give an IEnumerable of StaffUserGroup an IEnumerable of Anonymous. I believe this is because of the way you are selecting things in order to populate your ViewModel. Its hard to fix the code without know more about how things are structured. My recommendation here is go [look at how some other people are doing LINQ/EntityFramework in MVC](http://efmvc.codeplex.com/). It just takes a bit of practice until you get comfortable with how things are working.

Comment: This helped a good deal - thanks for such a detailed answer! The problem was solved by identifying the IEnumberable produced by the query, and generally tightening up on the scale of the ViewModel and what needed to by queried at all. Some good resources here too!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may be trying to put items of new type

`select new { grp.ID, grp.Desc, grp.Active, sub.Name, sub.Salt, sub.St }`

into a collection intended for items of type

`IEnumerable<Tbl_UserGroup> grpsQuery;`

Comment: Close, but it's actually because of the `select new {}` trying to be placed into the ViewModel (StaffUserGroup).

Comment: @RowanFreeman  yeah,figured. so it fits into Tbl_UserGroup? is that made specificlly for that?  so what's the fix?  is there a cast actually missing?

Comment: Hopefully my answer helped on the way to " 
identifying the IEnumberable produced by the query, and generally tightening up on the scale of the ViewModel and what needed to by queried at all. "